# SlickGrid: Invoke onCellChange

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am currently using SlickGrid in my app.  The problem that I am having is invoking the onCellChange when I click a button.  When I click on a cell, enter a value and move to another cell it will invoke the onCellChange event.

But when I click on a cell and then click on a button on the page, I need the OnCellChange event to fire.  Any way of accomplishing this?

What we are currently doing is when a value has changed in the cell, we save that as a shadow value to the server.  And then a person can commit those shadow values.  The problem that I have is you can change a cell value then hit a commit button. At this point the OnCellChange doesnt fire, so that shadow value for that cell has not been saved to the server.

Personally I don't agree with the way we are doing it, but that is out of my control

Thanks.
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call these lines on button click, it will fire the onCellChange event if there will be any active cell. Its working for me.

```
    if (grid.getActiveCell()) {
        var row = grid.getActiveCell().row;
        var cell = grid.getActiveCell().cell;
        grid.gotoCell(row, cell, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issue by calling the following method.

Slick.GlobalEditorLock.commitCurrentEdit();

Comment: That is too simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just call this line on button click.

```
args.commitChanges();
```

This will fire onChange event of SlickGrid